# Ошибка 500.0 при развертывании Flask-приложения на IIS 8

Tags: python, flask, iis

Есть небольшое приложение на Flask. Стоит задача развернуть его на IIS 8. Создал файл web.config, настроил всё, что можно уже в самом IIS, но постоянно получаю ошибку  500.0 - Internal Server Error "Произошла неизвестная ошибка FastCGI". Сначала думал, что виртуальное окружение мешает, решил написать обычный "Hello, world!" и протестить, но ошибка осталась. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? (понимаю сам, что разворачивать что-либо на IIS - уже не есть хорошо, но задача есть задача)